# unable to add maven compiler and surefire plugin in the existing pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Being new to maven ,i m uanble to add below plugin dependency in pom.xml,can someone please help me

- Need to add this

  org.apache.maven.plugins
   maven-compiler-plugin
   2.3.2.
   
   1.7
   1.7
   
   
     
   org.apache.maven.plugins
   maven-surefire-plugin
   2.12
   true
   
   
     testng.xml
- Exiting Pom.xml

  4.0.0
  www.asr.com
  asr
  0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

  ```
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
           <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
           <version>3.141.59</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
           <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
           <version>7.3.0</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
  ```

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: i dont know how to add below <plugins>
  <plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.2.</version>
<configuration>
<source>1.7</source>
<target>1.7</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>
  <plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.12</version>
<inherited>true</inherited>
<configuration>
<suiteXmlFiles>
  <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
</suiteXmlFiles>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>  under existing pom.xml

Comment: Welcome to SO! How shall we magically understand what you mean by `org.apache.maven.plugins maven-compiler-plugin 2.3.2. 1.7 1.7 org.apache.maven.plugins maven-surefire-plugin 2.12 true testng.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your plugins inside  tag.

For example:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>    
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>${asm.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>${asm.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
          <useFile>false</useFile>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/integration/**</exclude>
          </excludes>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
            <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Why are you adding asm for maven-compiler-plugin (use current version 3.8.1) Why adding surefire with integration tests? Convention is: Unit tests (`*Test.java`) running with surefire..Integration tests `*IT.java` with failsafe-plugin... Using version 2.22.2 of surefire/failsafe or if you need JDK13+ (If I correctly remember?) use 3.0.0-M5...

Comment: It is just an example to illustrate where the plugins must be placed in the pom file

Comment: Yes of course but the asm dependencies are simply not needed. Nor the whole configuration for tests ...better is to keep the convention over configuration paradigm...

Comment: @khmarbaise i have updated by plugin ,now can u please help me to where should placed this plugin my existing pom,xml